# Need to remove text with CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

I need to remove this 'string 4 here' text from checkout, unsure why it's there. Having trouble with the correct class/identifier:

[image]

Tried

.wc_payment_method payment_method_ppcp-credit-card-gateway data-order_button_text {
display: none;
}

Comment: You can hide it with CSS, but the better solution is to find that `var_dump()` which shows it within the PHP code, and comment that out.

Comment: Thanks @ron, can you give me an example of commenting out the .php code

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font size of the li to 0 and then apply a proper font size to li>label.